# How to fix random mouse movements and clicking?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, mouse, touchpad, vaio

I have a Sony Vaio with a Windows 10 partition and an Ubuntu 16.04 partition. Both worked fine. Now, on my Ubuntu partition, I have a mouse problem that occurs frequently. Sometimes my mouse will work as it should. Other times,it will constantly being jumping around the screen and clicking in random places. It does not seem to stop for anything, except for when it wants to stop. When it stops, everything works just fine. But, I know that it is inevitably going to start again. This will be days or even weeks without a problem. Then, days where I can not even use the Ubuntu partition at all. I do not even have to be touching the laptop at all for it to happen. I have tried turning off the touchpad and the touch screen. I have restarted my computer. I have used a new Ubuntu live USB. No matter what it will still do it. The Windows partition works just fine, which is the puzzling part.

Comment: What kind of mouse -- Bluetooth, USB, other wireless, etc., model?  Does the mouse take a battery?

Comment: I mean. The mouse really isn't the issue here. But it's a Bluetooth Logitech m217 with a battery

Comment: Sorry i see how that was confusing. I worded it badly. When I am referring to the mouse I mean the cursor on the screen